# Converting a typescript class object with dictionary to a JSON string

Tags: json, typescript, dictionary, mapping, stringify

I'm looking for a way to convert my typescript class with dictionary to a JSON object without the brackets.

this is my class

```
export class MediaTagRequest {
    tags: Map<string, string>; 
    constructor(tags: Map<string, string>) {
      this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

My instantiation

```
   let tags = new Map<string, string>();
   tags.set("city", "Karachi");  

   let mediatagRequest = new MediaTagRequest(tags);
   const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}   
   const body = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(mediatagRequest.tags.entries()));
```

My current output:

```
[["city","Karachi"]]
```

My desired output:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "city": "Karachi"
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of this to create `object` and then create response body using it

**Option 1**

```js
let jsonObject = {};
tags.forEach((value, key) => {  
    jsonObject[key] = value;
});
```

**Option 2**

```js
let jsonObject = {};
for (let entry of tags.entries()) {
    jsonObject[entry[0]] = entry[1];
}
```

**Option 3**

```js
let jsonObject = {};
for (let key of tags.keys()) {  
    jsonObject[key] = value;          
}
```

creating response body

```js
const body = JSON.stringify({
    tags: jsonObject
});
```

Comment: ah yes I already added the last line that you added to your solution. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a map to an object directly by using [`Map#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

Here is an example:

```js
const m = new Map();

m.set("foo", "hello");
m.set("bar", "world");

const obj = Object.fromEntries(m.entries());

console.log(obj);
```

You can further leverage [the replacer parameter of `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) to directly do this when converting an entire object:

```typescript
function mapReplacer(key: string | number | Symbol, value: any) {
  if (value instanceof Map) {
    return Object.fromEntries(value.entries());
  }
  
  return value;
}

class MediaTagRequest {
    tags: Map<string, string>; 
    constructor(tags: Map<string, string>) {
      this.tags = tags;
    }
}

let tags = new Map<string, string>();
tags.set("city", "Karachi");  

let mediatagRequest = new MediaTagRequest(tags);

console.log(JSON.stringify(mediatagRequest, mapReplacer))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBKBTdAbVCbAJwAoBrbATwC5EBnKYmMAc0QB9EwRkAjEp0QBlKvzh4ANIgBuqPCGx1UYKgEpEAbwBQiRDGCJSchdn1hGKonEMBZDBp169xbFBDEkAeT4ArbNAAdMDEcMgAomBMMNj0xvKKgdhRzLGkamoA3LqIAL45Oa7unrIJ2Nn52hAE9PSIttgAJjCoACqorDgAjoqMWjl6UB30dPboADyMzGzSUyysAHyZiAOIEAhTINBwZEOsI-UYk9EzDCeLjquDABYw9IF7dQC8iI-ZznnalXhur8OILzA2AA7ocJnNThDFulso9AvQ3KQAEQQGBQKhI6RIgDSqGIhFuSKyem02h+UBQTRae26vQpgJB9SpbQ6tNiUFIjyypPWFgk2ECeDgrFIAClhF4AHLw84GKikZDMmnYHrs6RoLC4AhEYgZIA)

JavaScript demo:

```js
function mapReplacer(key, value) {
  if (value instanceof Map) {
    return Object.fromEntries(value.entries());
  }
  
  return value;
}

class MediaTagRequest { 
    constructor(tags) {
      this.tags = tags;
    }
}

let tags = new Map();
tags.set("city", "Karachi");  

let mediatagRequest = new MediaTagRequest(tags);

console.log(JSON.stringify(mediatagRequest, mapReplacer))
```