# Converting a typescript class object with dictionary to a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, stringify

After some digging I decided my backend needed to consume duplicate keys and as a consequence my frontend can no longer send a dictionary as a JSON string.
See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565869/converting-a-typescript-class-object-with-dictionary-to-a-json-string).

After applying the solution provided

```
let mediatagRequest = new MediaTagRequest(tags);
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

let jsonObject = {};
for (let entry of mediatagRequest.tags.entries())
{
  jsonObject[entry[0]] = entry[1];
}

const body = JSON.stringify({
  tags: jsonObject
});
```

My current output (which is what I then wanted)

```
{
"tags": {
    "city": "Karachi"
}
```

However my needs have changed and after a bit of of struggle I couldn't get my desired output to be like this

```
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "city",
            "value": "Karachi"
        },
        {
            "key": "city",
            "value": "Mumbai"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could someone help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output you could use the `Object.entries()` function to get the key, value pairs separately. This code segment will turn an object into a list of objects with key value pairs:

```js
test_object = { 
  karachi: "dubai",
  mumbao: "moscow",
};

output = Object.entries(test_object).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value}));

console.log(output);
```

You can adapt this code to select the desired parts of your object and format them as you like. There are other `Object` functions you can see in the documentation.